# Proxmox Virtual Machine Bandwidth monitoring

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth, network-monitoring, bandwidth-control

I have been trying to find some tool to allow me to monitor and get stats from virtual machine network usage.

I have a proxmox host with several virtual machines, and I would like to have some sort of bandwidth monitoring, to allow me to stop virtual machines that exceed their quota.

It appears that Proxmox has this bandwidth monitoring feature planned, but since nothing has been made available so far, I wanted to implement this myself.

I can either have software installed on the proxmox host, or a virtual machine that would be responsible for this, as long as it is able to monitor network traffic or receive this information from the host.

The virtual machines I have inside proxmox are not containers, they are KVM virtual machines. I have done something similar in the past using iptables for OpenVZ, but I would like insights from someone with experience in this.

Is iptables the way to go? Should I be doing this inside the host, or with an external virtual machine? What would you recommend? I have gone through PRTG and Solarwinds, but as these might not be the best solutions, I wanted someone to shed some light into this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "TEE" target in "iptable" to mirror packets to a windows pc. Then you can install a passive bandwidth monitoring program(ie: WFilter) in this pc to monitor bandwidth and get report.

Please check this guide: https://web.archive.org/web/20160423201641/http://www.imfirewall.us/support/WFilter_4_1/Doc/deployment_iptables.htm

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Do you know any good linux alternative do the windows software you mentioned? I would prefer having a linux machine with some kind of software that would integrate with this, but it seems like a viable option.

Comment: Try flow-tools. This is generic way to account and log a traffic, which uses Cisco Netflow protocol.